# Why does Visual Studio sometimes show the path of a project file

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I compile my project, I get the following:

```
2>------ Build started: Project: Session, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: EmailValidation, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: Settings (Libraries\Elements\Settings), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
```

As you can notice, the project 'Settings' has its path displayed, but not the others.
Is there an option for this?
As we have a lot of nested folder, I'd like to enable this on all projects, but I have no idea how it appeared in the first place :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see the entire structure of your project, but this is usually added to project names to help resolve ambiguity. For instance, if your solution contained two projects named "Settings", the folder path is added to the display name so that you can tell which one is which.

There is no way to have this appear by default on all projects, short of a naming convention (like Libraries.Elements.Settings) that would help you know where they were in your file system. If you don't want it to appear, make sure that you have unique names for all of your projects.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked, and you were right, there was another project 'settings'.